# How to access the last child tag in a parent tag?

Tags: html, css

how will I access the last span element in my p tag? I have 4 span tags in my p tag I want to access the last one and do changes to it!! I've added styling to the `p span body{}` but they all are changing I want the last span tag to be accessible.

for example here is the code!

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an cum assum saperet mandamus. Amet commune
  vivendum mel at, movet mnesarchum honestatis cum et. At noluisse oporteat
  intellegebat his. Porro oportere ei quo. Ad eos possim omnium. Justo nonumes
  ad vel, eos id probo dictas, dicam dolorem theophrastus sit id. Nec te iusto
  <span>expetenda</span>
  , feugiat propriae cu vix. Nec omnis prompta ei, his no decore iisque admodum.
  Mea legimus fuisset id, his ei simul veniam mucius. Latine repudiandae sed te,
  soleat graeci efficiantur ne quo. Has viderer suscipit petentium ex. Sed cu
  recusabo aliquando, vel ad suscipit constituam quaerendum. Sea at enim
  sententiae, per ne tempor forensibus, duo in prompta sapientem. Platonem
  oportere est an. Iusto clita dissentiunt eos eu, te eros recteque vim, saepe
  vituperata id mea. Cu per admodum definiebas, reque invenire contentiones nam
  ad. An nec vero habeo, assentior
  <span>complectitur</span>
  duo ei. Sed suscipit moderatius ad. Putant aperiam impedit eos in, facer
  labitur voluptua pri no, et duis dolore meliore has. Ei mea nostro viderer, ne
  ullum eligendi quo, molestiae omittantur an ius. Fastidii philosophia at nam.
  Sed meis accusamus intellegebat in, modo ludus salutatus vis id, cu vis sint
  meliore dignissim. Per fuisset maiestatis eu, vocent vituperata reprimique nec
  ad. Nec ei delenit indoctum, pro harum percipit eu. Id liber
  <span>adipiscing</span>
  vim, eum cu epicurei deseruisse. Luptatum abhorreant ea eos.
</p>
```

Comment: `p span body { ... }` makes no sense with valid HTML semantics in mind. It would select an body elemen that is a child of a span which again is a child of a paragraph. As body can't be a child of those, it makes no sense.

Comment: sorry I wrote body by mistake I was just checking my code so it was in my mind!
it was **p span{}** thanks btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `last-of-type` selector

```
 p span:last-of-type
```

```css
p span:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an cum assum saperet mandamus. Amet commune vivendum mel at, movet mnesarchum honestatis cum et. At noluisse oporteat intellegebat his. Porro oportere ei quo. Ad eos possim omnium. Justo nonumes ad vel, eos id probo dictas,
  dicam dolorem theophrastus sit id. Nec te iusto
  <span>expetenda</span> , per admodum definiebas, reque invenire contentiones nam ad. An nec vero habeo, assentior
  <span>complectitur</span> duo ei. Sed suscipit moderatius ad. Putant aperiam impedit eos in, facer labitur voluptua pri no, et duis dolore meliore has. Ei mea nostro viderer, ne ullum eligendi quo, molestiae omittantur an ius. Fastidii philosophia at
  nam. Sed meis accusamus intellegebat in, modo ludus salutatus vis id, cu vis sint meliore dignissim. Per fuisset maiestatis eu, vocent vituperata reprimique nec ad. Nec ei delenit indoctum, pro harum percipit eu. Id liber
  <span>adipiscing</span> vim, eum cu epicurei deseruisse. Luptatum abhorreant ea eos.
</p>
```